# Sqlite3 Adding Columns

Tags: database, django, sqlite, addition

I'm working with Django and I added a new model variable meaning that I need another column in my sqlite3 data base.

I have heard that I'm supposed to use sqlite> , but I am really confused when I start to use it. So, if that is part of the solution, can you be very specific on what to do?

thanks

MORE INFO:

my app is called "livestream" & and my class is "Stream"
I added the model "channel"

returns ---->
DatabaseError: table livestream_stream has no column named channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can `ALTER TABLE` to add a new column in Sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) but not rename it nor drop it. Sqlite3 is a very useful database for bootstrapping your app. But sooner or later, you will need to change to a more robust/flexible database engine, say MySql or Postgresql.

Every time you add a new column to your models using Sqlite, you will need to recreate the schema (as far as I know, when you do migrations with Sqlite to add new columns, `south` complaints. see below). An approach I like more is use MySql with [`Django-South`](http://south.aeracode.org/) from the beginning, where I'm not sure about every aspect of my database.

`Django South` is an app for doing database migrations. It's very useful and [the docs are a good starting point for beginners.](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Every time you should make modifications to your database, you should consider them as migrations and use `South`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Nick thanks, Django South is great, I can't imagine any web framework without a good migration tool :)